# ADO.Net, Parametrized Queries and Plan Caching

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, ado.net

If I have a desktop application that uses ADO.Net to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 and uses an ad hoc parametrized query to retrieve data, what happens when two different instances of the app run the query? Does the first call get compiled and the second one use the in-memory version?

Example query:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
conn.Open();
string s = "SELECT email, passwd, login_id, full_name " + 
  "FROM members WHERE email = @email";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", email);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I'm noticing slow query performance the first time the query is fired and consecutive calls appear to be fine. I'm just wondering if this is across the board behavior for each instance of the app or if the first time the query is fired from one instance it improves the performance for all instances of the app that use this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server will have to analyze the query the first time it gets it, and find a reasonably well-performing execution plan for it.

Once it's done that, the query

```
SELECT email, passwd, login_id, full_name FROM members WHERE email = @email
```

and its execution plan are stored in plan cache.

As long as the plan cache has enough room, then any subsequent execution of that **exact same** query ("same" down to the last comma, space or anything! It must be **absolutely the same** SQL) will reuse that execution plan from the plan cache.

So yes - the very first time that query is executed (e.g. after a SQL Server restart), a slight delay will be noticeable, but once it's been executed and the query plan is cached, it should perform much better - for **all connections** to the SQL Server that will use that exact same query.

The requirement for the exact same query also illustrates why it's so bad - also from a performance point of view - to string together your SQL yourself and putting the query values into the actual query text - that way, each query with new values is a new SQL query text and the whole story has to be repeated for every single request. If you're using **parametrized** queries like you are, then the query remains the same and thus a cached execution plan can be reused - only the parameter values change, but that doesn't affect the query execution plan and the ability to reuse a cached plan

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Off to create stored procs for this application I inherited.

Answer (score 0):

I think compilation and plan cache does not matter here (you SQL-request is trivial). More important thing is disk cache. It seems, first time you have physical reads from disk, and next times you have logical reads (from the buffer cache). This disk cache is server wide.

You can try add command

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

befor you request, to force clean up disk cache. So you can check performance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, parametrized query execution plans are cashed and reused for every connection until they will be pushet from the cashe. You can check if the plan was recompiled in Profiler with event `SP:Recompile`. More about it you can read in MSDN Article [Execution Plan Caching and Reuse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

But, in your case, I think, more significant role plays cashing of the data. As long as you execute the query the first time data pages are loaded into RAM and stay there until they will be pushed from the cashe. It can affect execution time of following queries if they either pass the same value to `@email` parameter or you don't have index on field `email` (or both).